# SVN: Problems with tag creation in Eclipse with Subversive

Tags: eclipse, svn, tagging, subversive

I'm trying to create to create a tag in svn repo for my project. I use Eclipse and Subversive plugin. Every time I try tagging, I get the following error:

> Tag operation for some of selected resources failed.
>   svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: No write-lock in '/home/project/directory'

Where /home/directory is a directory in my project. I'm pretty sure that if I would delete the project and re-checkout it, then all will work.

Does anybody know what is the source of the problem and if there is a workaround to get it working without delete-checkout cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find that error popping up from [time (2008)](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.subversive/msg00800.html) (to [time (2009)](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&goto=32688&)) to [time (2010)](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@subversion.apache.org/msg00240.html).
Since there isn't any answer, that usually means the problem got away (like relaunching Eclipse was enough to pass that ordeal).
It could be a permission issue, or a resource (like a file or directory) blocked by a process.

But if it is more complicated, you still have [the command-line alternative](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-08/0326.shtml) (a [svn copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.tags.html))

---

[VJ.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242961/vj) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573231/svn-problems-with-tag-creation-in-eclipse-with-subversive/3573328#comment25819905_3573328):

> I eventually tried `svn update` which explained me that the write lock is present in another path of SVN.
> So **I issued a `svn clean` for the from the root tree**. Which cleared the issue.
> Post that, `svn update` worked as well as `svn switch`.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with using the svn copy through the SVN Repository perspective of subversive.

Comment: I was facing this same issue. I eventually tried `svn update` which explained me that ther write lock is present in another path of SVN. So I issued a `svn clean` for the from the root tree. which cleared the issue. Post that `svn update` worked as well as `svn switch`.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: @VJ. interesting. I have included your process in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for raising this issue! I just ran into this with Subversive 2.2.2 on Eclipse Indigo (3.7).

Cleaning up repository didn't work, but I noticed that the local copy has an old revision number (like 2, where the current is 37), although I am sure I committed before tagging.

So I ended up replacing the local code with the latest from repository, which updated the revision number. After that tagging worked like charm.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete the File called 'lock' in the .svn Directory, then svn should work again.
regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Clean up your project.

```
Right Click > Team > Cleanup
```

Then you can Switch to any branch you want

Answer (score 0):

same issue here(just tried to create a branch instead of a tag in this case). check out the ultimate solution :
1) commit the code.
2) disconnect the project from SVN.
3) delete the project from the workspace.
4) check out the project.
5) try again.

voila! 
its a bit overkill, but this works 100%

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution was a simple "svn up" at the top of the project directory.